# Build own carthage with swift version 5.0

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5, carthage

I am newly creating carthage and new to this.

I followed the tutorial from 
https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-create-a-framework-with-carthage-support-c30b596d3a7a

I created my own custom project for which I will create my carthage.
I followed the same steps and when I use the command

```
carthage build --no-skip-current
```

I get the error, as

```
error: SWIFT_VERSION '5.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2. (in target 'GSKit')
```

When I build the carthage with lower swift version by changing the setting in Build Setting to 4.0, this works well,
but I want to implement my own carthage framework with Swift 5.0
I am using `Xcode version 11.3`

```
Swift version 5.0
```

and carthage version on my machine is `0.34.0`

Can any one help me so that I can build my carthage in swift 5.0
what changes I am missing to make it compatible to work for swift 5.0

Thanks,

Comment: I suggest you to use cocoapods https://cocoapods.org/ . https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/2804

Comment: ohhh... I checked your shared link. But we have requirement for carthage only. not for pod. Thanks for input. Will check with the management for the same.